# MSBuild to a common output directory with nuget

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to change our build to use a common output directory (broadly along [these](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/04/04/using-a-common-intermediate-and-output-directory-for-your-solution/) lines), to reduce build times and the amount of space taken. However, I can't get nuget references to work correctly.

If I set `UseCommonOutputDirectory=true`, then the build does not copy any nuget references.

If I don't set this property, then the parallel build tasks end up conflicting when copying the same nuget dependencies into the common folder.

Is there a way to get the nuget dependencies copied exactly once? (There are no conflicting package versions, so it doesn't matter which project copies any given dependency)

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: @RikRak  sadly no.

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, I also have this issue.
To add to the context, there are at least two ways to compile in parallel:

- use msbuild's built in feature to parallel compile. I think for this there is some built in solution in NuGet, at least I see in the source code some SemaphoreSlim implementation.
- start individual msbuild processes in parallel from something else (e.g. Cake). For this I am not aware of a solution yet.

Here is my "workaround":

- Implement two MSBuild tasks that can Acquire and Release a *named* mutex
- Add a Target that runs Before _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal that takes the mutex
- Add a Target that runs after it that releases the mutex

The _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal is the actual MSBuild Target that does the copying of files from the NuGet directories into OutputPath / OutDir.

This "solution" assumes you have a central place where you can define custom targets for all your projects that you want to build in parallel (should be easy with SDK style projects - Directory.Build.targets).

As a bonus you can generate the mutex name from the OutDir so that building non-conflicting projects in parallel does not have any impact.